# Zenity --text with string variable

Tags: linux, bash

I'm wondering how I can pass a string containing spaces to Zenity for the text argument as my current method is truncating/failed to evaluate all the text after the first space.

Here is an MVP which shows the issue:

#### Script

```
#!/bin/bash

a="test test test"
test_func() {
  echo "$@"
  $(zenity --info --text "test test")
  $(zenity --info --text "$@")
}

test_func ${a}
```

#### Output

```
$> test test test
$> (zenity info window with test test as text)
$> (zenity info window with test) *** should contain "test test test"
```

Comment: Is the intent to pass a single argument to `test_func` and have it be the argument to `zenity`'s` `--text` option? Or to pass N arguments to `test_func` and have them *all* be the `--text` option's (single) argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `"$*"` instead of `"$@"`.

Manual for `"$@"` (emphasis mine):

> Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one. **When the expansion occurs within double quotes, each parameter expands to a separate word**. That is, "$@" is equivalent to "$1" "$2" ... If the double-quoted expan sion occurs within a word, the expansion of the first parameter is joined with the beginning part of the orig‐ inal word, and the expansion of the last parameter is joined with the last part of the original word. When there are no positional parameters, "$@" and $@ expand to nothing (i.e., they are removed).

And for `"$*"`:

> Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one. When the expansion is not within double quotes, each positional parameter expands to a separate word. In contexts where it is performed, those words are subject to further word splitting and pathname expansion. When the expansion occurs within double quotes, it expands to a single word with the value of each parameter separated by the first character of the IFS special variable. That is, "$*" is equivalent to "$1c$2c...", where c is the first character of the value of the IFS variable. If IFS is unset, the parameters are separated by spaces. If IFS is null, the parameters are joined without intervening separators.

Alternatively, you could quote `${a}` to pass `a` as a single argument instead of splitting on spaces.

Comment: Using `"${a}"` at the call site would fix the specific problem here (though the `"$*"` suggestion is also useful if multiple arguments need to be combined into the zenity single argument).